# How do I concatenate my relative path before ImageColumn in filamentphp?

Tags: php, laravel, filamentphp

I'm using Laravel Filamentphp as my admin dashboard and filament wants to input the relative path of the image in the database but I only want to store the file name of the image.

```
`ImageColumn::make('image')`
```

is there a way to modify this so that I can concatenate the relative directory

```
/products/{category_id}/'image'
```

also I have the products separated per category.

I tried to make a function and simple concatenate but I'm having issues.

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually trying to make things more complicated than it actually is. Lmao. I just placed the pictures in the `/storage/app/public` folder to skip doing this code.